# A question on bi-projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a bi-homogeneous polynomial with integer coefficients in $\mathbf{x} = (x_0, x_1, x_2)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (y_0, y_1, y_2, y_3)$ of bi-degree $(d_1, d_2)$, say. Suppose that the hypersurface $Y$ defined by $F(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y}) = 0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^3$ is smooth. For each fixed $\mathbf{x}$, denote by $F_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{y}) = F(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y})$, which is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d_2$ in the $y$-variables. Define $Z_{\mathbf{x}}$ for the surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ defined by $F_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{y}) = 0$.

We now suppose that $d_2 \geq 4$. Generically, surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d \geq 4$ do not contain lines: indeed, degree $d$ surfaces typically do not contain any curves of degree less than $d-2$. Also, the generic degree $d$ surface is smooth.

For $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{P}^2$ we say $Z_{\mathbf{x}}$ is *generic* if $Z_{\mathbf{x}}$ is smooth (as a surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$) and does not contain a curve of degree less than $d_2 - 2$. Let $U$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{P}^2$ such that $Z_{\mathbf{x}}$ is generic. Is $U$ Zariski-closed in $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: The locus $U \subseteq \mathbf P^2$ where the fibre of $Y \subseteq \mathbf P^2 \times \mathbf P^3 \to \mathbf P^2$ is smooth and does not contain a member of some fixed (bounded) family of positive dimensional subvarieties is always Zariski open. What's not clear is whether it's nonempty.

Comment: Geometrically what's going on is that you have a map $\mathbf P^2 \to \mathbf P^N$ to the space of degree $d_2$ hypersurfaces, which has some closed locus $W$ of hypersurfaces containing a curve of degree $< d_2 - 2$. If $W$ contains a $\mathbf P^2$, you're in trouble: then you can make a map $\mathbf P^2 \to \mathbf P^N$ whose image lands inside $W$, hence every fibre contains a curve of degree $< d_2 - 2$. At least looking at dimensions, there is no clear reason why $W$ cannot contain a $\mathbf P^2$ if $d_2 \gg 0$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn is the value of $d_1$ relevant here? In the application I have in mind one can assume $d_1 \geq 4$, though it would be nice if this assumption is not needed.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn also for your comment that it is difficult to verify if $U$ is non-empty, in an explicit family does it suffice to give just one element $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{P}^2$ such that $Z_{\mathbf{x}}$ is both smooth and free of degree $d_2 - 2$ curves?

Comment: I think it should be sufficient to exhibit a single such fibre, yeah. Because the family of degree $d_2 - 2$ curves is bounded, the incidence space $\{(C,x)\ |\ C \subseteq Z_x, \deg C < d_2 -2\}$ is of finite type. At least this proves the image in $\mathbf P^2$ is constructible. As I'm writing this, I realise that I'm not entirely sure how to prove the space of degree $< d_2 -2$ curves is proper, but that would imply closedness of the image.